# Symfony2 Upload Form & User ID

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I'm trying to create a form in the User Bundle for Symfony where I want to allow users to upload photos and eventually use them as a profile picture.

Using this for example: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

I want to figure out how to assign the user **ID** to the photo while uploading the image as just an `"ID".png` itself.

Would anyone know? This would take using Doctrine of course.

Comment: is the photo an attribute of the user or is it an entity ?

Comment: @RachidO The photo would be an entity. I want to keep a separate photo database so that loading the images by user ID would be a lot easier. I'm thinking something across Mongo, but maybe Doctrine sounds easier since I've never used Mongo yet. I would have for the Message Bundle. Better yet, everything if it means better performance.

I'm trying to do the same for Zip Codes to load cities, but I'll look at that later and create a separate Question post.

Comment: do you use Lifecycle Callbacks ?

Comment: @RachidO I do, this feature itself will have to be made from scratch though. I haven't been successful on this type of entity. And this isn't even the hardest goal.